# How do I compare part of a field to another part of a field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, comparison

This is to try to identify a potential duplicate user in my system, where he 
would create two entries with:
my.name.totoro@shibly.**com** and my.name.totoro@shibly.**net**
How do I find all the matches where the only difference is the last part of the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient but it does the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE LEFT(email, LENGTH(email) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(email))) IN 
(
   SELECT LEFT(email, LENGTH(email) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(email))) AS common
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY LEFT(email, LENGTH(email) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(email)))
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caec1f/1)

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6fa/2

```
SELECT 
  u.email,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.email) clones
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users c
ON u.id <> c.id
  AND  SUBSTRING(u.email,1,LENGTH(u.email)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email,'.',-1))) 
       = SUBSTRING(c.email,1,LENGTH(c.email)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.email,'.',-1))) 
GROUP BY u.id
```

This query return too many records like `.com = .net` as well as `.net = .com`:

```
rec1 = my.name.totoro@shibly.com    my.name.totoro@shibly.net
rec2 = my.name.totoro@shibly.net    my.name.totoro@shibly.com
```

but it can be resolved by adding:

```
WHERE u.email = "my.name.totoro@shibly.com"
```

which will return all duplicates for particular email when needed.